# Let R and S be reflexive relations on A. Suppose that R is also transitive. Prove S ⊆ R if and only if (S ◦ R) = R.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To prove this, I was going to assume S ⊆ R and prove (S ◦ R) = R, then do it the other way, assume (S ◦ R) = R and prove S ⊆ R. Then to do the first part I was going to do what my professor calls the "double subset strategy," where, to prove an equality you let (x,y) be in (S ◦ R) and prove it is in R, and then go the other way, let (x,y) be in R and prove (x,y) is in (S ◦ R).

I'm not sure how to prove (x,y) is in (S ◦ R). Am I taking a legit approach here? And how do I prove (x,y) is in (S ◦ R)?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. As for the specific question, suppose that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$; to show that $\langle x,y\rangle\in S\circ R$ you must show that there is some $z\in A$ such that $\langle x,z\rangle\in R$ and $\langle z,y\rangle\in S$. (Informally, if you can get from $x$ to $y$ with the relation $R$, then there is some $z\in A$ such that you can get from $x$ to $z$ via $R$ and then from $z$ to $y$ via $S$. Use the hypothesis that $S$ is reflexive. It gives you at least one possible $z$ such that $\langle z,y\rangle$ is known to be in $S$; does that $z$ help you here?